# Use fusedlocationapi to get location without requesting for location updates after a time interval

Tags: android, geolocation, location, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I am using google's fusedlocationapi in android for getting user's current latitude and longitude, now according to my use case i only want to get user's current location only when user clicks on a button, now i thought that instead of requesting for location updates again and again between a time interval i can use something different so that my user's battery will not get drained much, i searched a lot of posts on SO and on other communities also but didn't find anything useful. Now can anybody please tell me how can i find something that will work for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove the location updates when you get a location

```
  LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
  mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
  mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1001);
  mLocationRequest.setNumUpdates(1);
  mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
  LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, new com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
              // save your location here

            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes i thought about the same thing but the problem is when user clicks again on the button then i want to fetch updated location but according to your code it will give last old location because as now you are not requesting for location updates. Please correct me if i am thinking in wrong direction.

Comment: When the user clicks again, you just start this function again and save the updated location

Comment: yes but it takes mostly about 5 secs of time to fetch the location but i don't want that much delay, how can in real apps(e.g Zomato, etc) when you click on auto-detect they fetch location instantly ?? there is no time delay ??

Comment: i am waiting for your response @Ahmed Abidi

Comment: I suspect the Zomato app is requesting continous location updates with PRIORITY_NO_POWER in onResume.